# Tracking visit source iframe form

Tags: iframe, google-analytics

On my page (domain x) i have form in iframe (on domain y). I want to track conversion (click on submit button). I have GA in iframe form but but form after sending is redirecting to domain x. In GA I have conversions but I as a medium I can see always (direct)(none).

Answer (score 0):

You need try use cross-domain tracking settings in GATC on form page and in iFrame too. https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cross-domain